# Homomorphism from Lie algebra to Algebra. Understand Lie algebra as an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

- A Lie algebra is an algebra under the Lie bracket, as multiplication.

  > A Lie algebra doesn't have a 'standard multiplication' i.e. $[x,y]=xy-yx$, when not a nice Lie algebra, you cannot necessary write $xy$ as some reduced element, and we can only think of these as words. It just happens that for a matrix algebra, we can actually multiply $x$ and $y$.

Actually the above was poorly formed, since I have implicitly used concatenation as multiplication when I wrote $xy$. This could only make sense if this did indeed have algebra structure, and then induced Lie algebra structure by defining $[x,y]=xy-yx$.

- A homomorphism from a Lie algebra $L$ to an algebra $A$, is a linear map $\psi:L\to A$ such that $\psi([a,b])=\psi(a)\psi(b)$. Where the only reason why we have for $\phi:L\to L'$, two Lie algebras, $\phi([a,b])=[\phi(a),\phi(b)]$ is because it is preserving the 'Lie-multiplication'.

Are these three dot points correct? Or I am mistaken.

Comment: The third point is incorrect.  Rather, every associative algebra $A$ has a Lie algebra structure by defining $[x,y] = xy - yx$.  A homomorphism $L \rightarrow A$ is meant to be as Lie algebras.

Comment: @D_S But if point $1$ is correct, then point $3$ follows, as a homomorphism of algebras. So point three would only be wrong if we were referring to a homomorphism of Lie algebras, with Lie algebra structure induced on A?

Comment: It's just a definition.  Nobody does things as in your point three.

Comment: I think point 2. is misunderstood now. I guess we only use this Lie bracket in the case that the vectorspace is indeed an algebra with $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ and then we induce Lie algebra structure.

Comment: @D_S I know, but by definition, a homomorphism as algebras, is indeed as in my point three, right? Then one should be careful with terminology such as homomorphism of Lie algebras, or homomorphism of algebras

Comment: Everything makes more sense if you think of associativity as a required part of the definition of an algebra.  A Lie algebra is then a totally different mathematical structure than an algebra.  In particular, a Lie algebra is not an algebra, though every algebra inherits the structure of a Lie algebra.

Comment: I don't know if I want to swallow that pill (requiring associativity to define an algebra). Although it does raise to me a question

Comment: Okay if we do it your way: when people talk about a homomorphism $\phi: L \rightarrow A$, they mean you forget about the existing algebra structure on $A$, and define a new one by setting $x \ast y$ to be $xy - yx$.  Then $\phi$ is meant to be a homomorphism of algebra with the new algebra structure on $A$.  Clear?

Comment: Also to motivate my change in the definition of an algebra: the only nonassociative algebras anybody cares about are Lie algebras.  So you might as well just have a category of algebras, required to be associative, and another category of Lie algebras.